# Load text file into array struct

Tags: ios, swift

This is the `struct` of my array:

```
struct Question {
    let imgName: String
    let questionText: String
    let options: [String]
    let correctAns: Int
    var wrongAns: Int
    var isAnswered: Bool
}

var questionsArray = [Question]()
```

Here is how the array is populated currently:

```
let que1 = Question(imgName: "img1", questionText: "What is 2 x 2 ?", options: ["2", "4", "8", "6"], correctAns: 1, wrongAns: -1, isAnswered: false)
let que2 = Question(imgName: "img2", questionText: "What is 4 + 2 ?", options: ["9", "4", "3", "6"], correctAns: 3, wrongAns: -1, isAnswered: false)
questionsArray = [que1, que2]
```

I would like to put data in a text file and populate my `questionsArray`. So I created a file, data.txt and put it into bundle. Below is the content of data.txt. Each question is separated by a new line.

```
Question(imgName: "img1", questionText: "What is 2 x 2 ?", options: ["2", "4", "8", "6"], correctAns: 1, wrongAns: -1, isAnswered: false)
Question(imgName: "img2", questionText: "What is 4 + 2 ?", options: ["9", "4", "3", "6"], correctAns: 3, wrongAns: -1, isAnswered: false)
```

I tried to use this method:

```
var arrayOfStrings: [String]?

do {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "txt") {
        let data = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        arrayOfStrings = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        questionsArray = arrayOfStrings
    }
} catch let err as NSError {
    print(err)
}
```

However, I received an error, `Cannot assign value of type '[String]?' to type '[Question]'` for the line `questionsArray = arrayOfStrings`.

How to solve this?

Comment: Your **arrayOfStrings** is not yet set to an array of Question objects. So you try to set a [String] type to a variable of type [Question]. **arrayOfStrings** need to be first converted back to [Question]

Comment: `arrayOfString` is `[String]` and `questionsArray` is  `[Question]`. The types clearly don't match. That's what the error message says. How are the single lines organized to separate the fields? I highly recommend to save the data as JSON or Property List and decode it directly into the struct.

Comment: Your questionsArray is array of Question struct and you are assigning array of string directly to array of your struct `questionsArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick tutorial for a better data management. It uses widely your code.

- Create a new Blank Playground, platform **macOS** (important!). You can keep the playground to add more questions.
- Paste this code, it creates a JSON file `questions.json` on the desktop

  ```
  struct Question : Encodable {
      let imgName: String
      let questionText: String
      let options: [String]
      let correctAns: Int
      var wrongAns: Int
      var isAnswered: Bool
  }

  let que1 = Question(imgName: "img1", questionText: "What is 2 x 2 ?", options: ["2", "4", "8", "6"], correctAns: 1, wrongAns: -1, isAnswered: false)
  let que2 = Question(imgName: "img2", questionText: "What is 4 + 2 ?", options: ["9", "4", "3", "6"], correctAns: 3, wrongAns: -1, isAnswered: false)
  let questionsArray = [que1, que2]

  do {
      let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(questionsArray)
      let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Desktop/questions.json")
      try jsonData.write(to: url)
  } catch {
      print(error)
  }
  ```
- Drag the file from the desktop into your project navigator. Make sure that `Copy if needed` is checked.
- Use this code in your project

  ```
  struct Question : Decodable {
      let imgName: String
      let questionText: String
      let options: [String]
      let correctAns: Int
      var wrongAns: Int
      var isAnswered: Bool
  }

  var questionsArray = [Question]()


  let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "questions", withExtension: "json")!
  let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
  questionsArray = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Question].self, from: data)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Saving the data in a file is a good idea. But in the format of txt and especially in this format below is definitely not a good idea :

```
Question(imgName: "img1", questionText: "What is 2 x 2 ?", options: ["2", "4", "8", "6"], correctAns: 1, wrongAns: -1, isAnswered: false)
```

You should use the json format which is perfectly suitable for this case. You save the data into a file.json.

How to do it ? Add the Codable protocol to your struct Question:

```
struct Question: Codable {
    let imgName: String
    let questionText: String
    let options: [String]
    let correctAns: Int
    var wrongAns: Int
    var isAnswered: Bool
}
```

Then encode the data :

```
do {
    let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(questionsArray)
    // Write encoded data to file
} catch let err {
    print(err)
}
```

And when you want retrieve back the data:

```
let data = Data(contentsOf: url)
do {
    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Question].self, from: data)
} catch let err {
    // Failed to decode data
    print(err)
}
```